# Accessing Java Web App from different machine using IP of server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I have deployed a web application (name: SDCS) on tomcat 6.0 server that compares image files from user-provided folder path.

The application is working perfectly fine on the server and its able to pick the images from the folder and proceed.

But when I access it from another machine on the same network by using server's IP, it opens up perfectly but obviously it doesn't pick up the images as it is not able to find the user-provided folder path on the server and the code breaks.
Please suggest some workarounds for this problem.

Link when accessing on Server: localhost:8080/SDCS/

Link when accessing on another machine: Server's IP:8080/SDCS

Comment: Link when accessing on same machine or another machine is correct but please make sure that that folder has full fledged permissions r-w-x and also to that images

Comment: It has got all the permissions (r-w-x). No problem from that side.

Comment: Is it throwing any Exception such as java.io.FileNotFoundException, did you checked log when you execute in another machine?

Comment: Yes, it is throwing NPE when I try to access files from that folder

Comment: Actually it should not throw Null Pointer if the code is correct with full flexibility ,there may be cases to throw FileNotFound Exception or IOException  in these type of scenarios

Comment: You're not getting the problem. Code is quite correct but obviously the server wouldn't be able to access a folder on client's machine directly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make those images available as a url. Maybe create a servlet to load them and load them via that and not from the file system

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. Can you please elaborate more how to make those images available as URL? Not that much of dev experience here. Really appreciated.